Python debuger with vscode ipmort local files error
When I try to launch vscode debugger it fails on the line where I try to import something from local files saying that the module is not installed.

No module named 'app'
File "/path/to/my_project/app/script.py", line 1, in 
from app.other_cript import helper
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'


To allow vscode to recognise local files as modules you need to create
launch.json at path /path/to/my_project/.vscode
Content of the launch.json should be
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python Debugger: Current File",
            "type": "debugpy",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "env": {"PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}:${workspaceFolder}/app"}
        }
    ]
}

After that you should be able to run your script without errors

